# how can i check if directory exist and add a compile definition in cmake

Tags: cmake

I have this if-statement from a Makefile

```
ifneq ($(shell test -e /usr/include/linux/signalfd.h && echo 1),)
CFLAGS += -DUSE_SIGNALFD
endif
```

trying to translate it to cmake but not sure what is the best way.
I know that I would have to add a `target_compile_definitions(tgtd PRIVATE -DUSE_SIGNALF)`

not sure how to work with `CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS`

Comment: What research did yo do? Isn't checking if you're on linux enough - any linux will have `signalfd.h`, no? Cmake has great documentation - did you browse it or google on how to check if a include file exists in cmake? What did the research resulted in? Have you tried anything? `how to work with CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS` ? It's related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [check include file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.19/module/CheckIncludeFile.html)...

```
include(CheckIncludeFile)
check_include_file("linux/signalfd.h" has_signalfd)
if(has_signalfd)
   target_compile_definitions(tgtd PRIVATE USE_SIGNALF)  # NO -D !
endif()
```

You may check if file exists with `if(EXISTS ...`, but note that that does **not** mean that the file will be available to `#include`, ex. in case of cross compiling.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not able to find Cmake example for this problem. The Cmake documatation is not always clear to me as a newbie. I did google, ususally stackoverflow is my last resort. I was able to do this 'find_library(LUA_LIB lua)
if(NOT LUA_LIB)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "lua library not found")
endif()' but not sure it helps.